# Wolfram Engine beginner's question: how to Sum?

Tags: python, free-wolfram-engine

I really like the idea of the Wolfram Engine, and in particular using it via the python client library. However, I've having trouble understanding the syntax for even simple commands: is there some documentation anywhere (beyond the very limited [reference docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/index.html))? In particular, is there documentation of the API and how standard commands from Mathematica map across?

The particular simple example I'm unable to get work is just a simple `Sum` call. I expected this to be accessed via something like

```python
from wolframclient.language import wl
wl.Sum(1, ['i', 1, 5])
```

but this gives a list of errors (`Raw object i cannot be used as an iterator.` etc). How is it intended to use simple functions like this?

Comment: Why not something like `wlexpr('Sum[1, {i, 1, 5}]')`, which you can pass along to `session.evaluate()`?

Comment: I'm looking to programmatically generate the arguments, so `wlexpr` will be just a bit more painful as everything's a string -- fine if that's the only option though!

Comment: I get the same error in Mathematica from `Sum[1, {"i", 1, 5}]`.  Maybe your `'i'` is translated to a string, not a `Symbol`.

Comment: `wl.Sum(1, [wl.Symbol('i'), 1, 5])` gives a similar error (`Tag Symbol in Symbol[i] is Protected`) - how are symbols treated by Mathematica when used as dummy variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is working example that may be useful as a starting point.  Note that the fourth line (`with ... as s:`) contains a linux path name that may have to be removed and/or replaced for other systems.

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
import sys

with WolframLanguageSession("/usr/local/bin/MathKernel") as s:
    ## print("session is open", s, "\n\n")

    # summand is equal to the index
    try :
        i = wl.expr('i')
        f = i
        result = s.evaluate(wl.Sum(f, [i, 1, 5]))
        print(result,"\n")
    except :
        print("first one failed")
        print(sys.exc_info()[1])

    # summand is a pure function evaluated at the index
    try :
        i = wl.expr('i')
        f = wlexpr('1/(2^#) &')                         # it's wlexpr, not wl.expr
        result = s.evaluate(wl.Sum(f(i), [i, 1, 5]))
        print(result,"\n")
    except :
        print("second one failed")
        print(sys.exc_info()[1])

(*   15 

     Rational[31, 32]   *)
```